# How to add hours, minutes and seconds to a datetime column in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sqldatetime

I have the following datetime column in my table *"UpdatedTime"*

Sample value: `2021-12-31 00:00:00.000`

I need to manipulate the hours, minutes and seconds to become `23:59:59` (i.e. a second before midnight.)

Expected Value:  `2021-12-21 23:59:59.000`

Thanks in advance

Comment: What dbms are you talking about? For MSSQL there is [`DATEADD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql) for myql there is [`ADDTIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime)

Comment: Hello, i m talking about MSSQL

Comment: December 321'st?

Comment: Your sample value infers this, but it depends if your datetimes always start at 00:00:00.000.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use `dateadd()`, but I would phrase it as:

```
select dateadd(second, 24 * 60 * 60 - 1, UpdatedTime)
```

Or just add a time value:

```
select UpdatedTime + '23:59:59'
```

Comment: this work as well. very simple and efficient. thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DATEADD() function as follows (check [SQL Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=29a8739c478ca809dfe42ad62ac4af5e) for clarity):

```
SELECT 
  *, 
  DATEADD(hour, 23, DATEADD(minute, 59, DATEADD(second, 59, date_))) as updated_datetime
FROM dates_;
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
date_                   updated_datetime
----------------------- -----------------------
2021-01-01 00:00:00.000 2021-01-01 23:59:59.000
```

Comment: Awesome! Feel free to upvote the answer so other people will be able to refer it as correct :) Thanks!

Comment: accepted the answer instead. unable to upvote cause not enought reputation. once again, thank you

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, @DaleK! Edited the reply accordingly and will not ask for upvotes again.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on a sufficiently modern version of MSSQL, this should work:

```
DECLARE @dt DATETIME = '2021-12-31 00:00:00.000'
SELECT DATETIMEFROMPARTS(
    DATEPART(YEAR, @dt),
    DATEPART(MONTH, @dt),
    DATEPART(DAY, @dt),

    23, /* hour */
    59, /* minute */
    59, /* second */

    0 /* fractional seconds*/

);
```

---

I'd also be remiss if I didn't mention that by calculating the datetime you've requested, you might be employing an antipattern. If your goal in calculating the above is to do something like:

```
select *
from dbo.yourTable
where DateCreated >= @StartOfDay
   and DateCreated <= @EndOfDay;
```

You'll eventually have an issue with the above if the DateCreated column admits a value like '2021-12-21 23:59:59.997'.

If that is indeed your goal, it's better to write that query as:

```
select *
from dbo.yourTable
where DateCreated >= @StartOfDay
   and DateCreated < @StartOfNextfDay;
```

That is use a half-open interval instead of a fully closed interval.

Comment: yep, that is indeed a good point. I should consider the fraction of a seconds as well. thank you!